# Retrieving Servlet info from non-form parts

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, servlets

I am trying to create an application that reads JSON strings.

Right now: I can input a JSON string through Java, write it to an HTML document and have a JavaScript application read it; which then parses it and writes it to the same HTML application.  I need to know how, using Java, to read the HTML that it gets written to so I can use that data. It is important to note this HTML file is all generated by code so there is no actual text file to read.

I realize this is a roundabout way of doing it, but up until this point it has worked. My question is simple: How can I read an HTML page in a part that is not in a `<form>` through either regular Java or Servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that only by parsing the HTML in Java. And, there are some open source libraries that does this job for you.

Here is one that you can use.
http://jsoup.org/